# Start animation when scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

I have spend all day looking for an easy way to make my animation start after I have scrolled to a specific place on the page.

My css

```
.animation {
 width: 50%; 
 float: left; 
 position: relative; 
 -webkit-animation-name: test; 
 -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 3;
 -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
 animation-name: test; 
 animation-duration: 4s; 
 animation-iteration-count: 1; 
 animation-fill-mode: forwards; }
```

And my HTML

```
<div class="container">

<div class="animation">

Content goes here...

</div>

</div>
```

I wonder how to make the animation start when I scroll to the class container.

Comment: use js and add class to div when it is visible on the screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: You could use a library like https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible instead of trying to figure it out yourself

Answer (score 14):

Javascript

```
var $window = $(window);
var $elem = $(".animation")

function isScrolledIntoView($elem, $window) {
    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    if (isScrolledIntoView($elem, $window)) {
        $elem.addClass("animate")
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="animation">Content goes here...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.animation.animate {
    animation: pulse 5s infinite;//change this to whatever you want
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toby3105/749yxgdk/2/) to play with (don't forget to scroll)

Answer (score 3):

@WebWeb , you can try this simple formula :

```
$(window).on('scroll' , function(){
    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    element_pos = $(yourelement).offset().top + $(yourelement).height() ;
    if (scroll_pos > element_pos) {
        $(yourelement).addClass('add-anim');
    };

})
```

It is basically checking if the windows scroll position is higher than that of the elements offset from the top of the document(plus the element's height) . It is an age-old formula.

**[FIDDLE AND DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/749yxgdk/3/)**

If you are lazy like me though, you can go for [waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) an amazing library.

Answer (score 3):

no need to wonder about it... just use it

[GITHUB](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

download animate.css and implement this in

```
<script src="http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<script>
new WOW().init();
</script>


<div class="wow bounceInLeft animated">
              <h2>animated heading</h2>
</div>
```

try this code...

[this link for more](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

(these classes can be used)

```
bounce
flash
pulse
rubberBand
shake
headShake
swing
tada
wobble
jello
bounceIn
bounceInDown
bounceInLeft
bounceInRight
bounceInUp
bounceOut
bounceOutDown
bounceOutLeft
bounceOutRight
bounceOutUp
fadeIn
fadeInDown
fadeInDownBig
fadeInLeft
fadeInLeftBig
fadeInRight
fadeInRightBig
fadeInUp
fadeInUpBig
fadeOut
fadeOutDown
fadeOutDownBig
fadeOutLeft
fadeOutLeftBig
fadeOutRight
fadeOutRightBig
fadeOutUp
fadeOutUpBig
flipInX
flipInY
flipOutX
flipOutY
lightSpeedIn
lightSpeedOut
rotateIn
rotateInDownLeft
rotateInDownRight
rotateInUpLeft
rotateInUpRight
rotateOut
rotateOutDownLeft
rotateOutDownRight
rotateOutUpLeft
rotateOutUpRight
hinge
rollIn
rollOut
zoomIn
zoomInDown
zoomInLeft
zoomInRight
zoomInUp
zoomOut
zoomOutDown
zoomOutLeft
zoomOutRight
zoomOutUp
slideInDown
slideInLeft
slideInRight
slideInUp
slideOutDown
slideOutLeft
slideOutRight
slideOutUp
```

Comment: https://github.com/graingert/wow is the alternative for http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW (this domain is parked)

Answer (score 2):

You can try [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html) it's quick and simple for integrate animation on scroll when element is visible on page. I create simple demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/css/libs/animate.css">
    <style>

body {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div style="height: 110vh">
</div>

<div class="wow bounceInLeft">
  Animation start when Visible
</div>

<div data-wow-delay=".5s" class="wow bounceInLeft">
  Animation start when Visible after .5s delay
</div>

<div data-wow-delay="1s" class="wow bounceInLeft">
  Animation start when Visible after 1s delay
</div>

<div data-wow-delay="2s" class="wow bounceInLeft">
  Animation start when Visible after 2s delay
</div>

<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 300px;">
  <span data-wow-delay="" class="wow bounceInDown">Link 1</span>
  <span data-wow-delay=".1s" class="wow bounceInDown">Link 3</span>
  <span data-wow-delay=".2s" class="wow bounceInDown">Link 3</span>
  <span data-wow-delay=".3s" class="wow bounceInDown">Link 4</span>
</div>


<script src="http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
<script>
 new WOW().init();
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is anyone wants to use this for an animation that should run when you **open the page, hover it, when you scroll and run again when you scroll back**, here is how I solved it.

I used what @robert used and added some refinements.

I made this fiddle for this https://jsfiddle.net/hassench/rre4qxhf/

So there you go:

```js
var $window = $(window);
var $elem = $(".my-image-container");
var $gotOutOfFrame = false;

function isScrolledIntoView($elem, $window) {
  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop) && $gotOutOfFrame);
}

function isScrolledOutView($elem, $window) {
  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemBottom < docViewBottom) && (elemTop < docViewTop));
}
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($elem, $window)) {
    $gotOutOfFrame = false;
    $elem.addClass("animate");
    $(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $elem.removeClass("animate");

      }, 1500);
    });
  }
  if (isScrolledOutView($elem, $window)) {
    $gotOutOfFrame = true;
    $elem.removeClass("animate");
  }
});
```

```css
.my-image-container {
  top: 50px;
  max-width: 22%;
}

.my-image-container:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.my-image-container .my-image {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -o-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

.animate {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;
  -moz-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  -o-animation-delay: 0.5s;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
The animation will run when you firt open the page,<br> 

and when you hover it,<br> 

and when you scroll out then in. <br>

<div class="my-image-container">
  <img class="my-image" 
  src="http://www.lifeofpix.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/img-5831.jpg">
</div>
<br> Scroll down then back up
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
scroll up
```